# Changing Date Format to dd/MM/yyyy After conversion from Timezone

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project that requires me to be comparing the date stored as string in database to the current date.

This particular application works in localhost but on live server, it seems to be picking the date of the server. I am resident in West Central Africa. How do i get the Date returned by my converted timezone in the format dd/MM/yyyy and not MM/dd/yyyy that it is seeing it.

Below is a code snippet.

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow ;
        var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Central Africa Standard Time");

       
        DateTime currentTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, zone);

        var loanDates = currentTime.Date;
      
        var OldloanDate = loanDates.ToShortDateString();

        var nloanDate = DateTime.ParseExact(OldloanDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;

       var loanDate = nloanDate.ToShortDateString();
```

I want the loanDate to be in string form and of the format dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Why are you converting a date to a string and then parsing it right back? `DateTime` does **not** have a format. It only has a format when you convert it to a string. To answer your question `loanDates.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Central Africa Standard Time");
var currentTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, zone);
var loanDate = currentTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Replace("-", "/");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That part is resolved. I have a field in database stored as string and i need to convert it back to datetime and then compare if it equals to loanDate above, Any headsup to it? My head is full to even walk around it

Comment: Yes , I can post the answer immedialely. But this resource policy is one question in the time. People vouted already and they maybe will not be vouted for the second answer.  Pls  ask the new question.

Comment: Posted here:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080060/retrieve-a-string-from-database-and-compare-with-date